# How to convert Character Numerals into Numeric format?

Tags: abap

I am trying to convert some String of Characters into Numeric form and then further incrementing it.

For Example : XX1-XXXXX.01.01.01.01 should be incremented to XX1-XXXXX.01.01.01.02 and if it reaches to XX1-XXXXX.01.01.01.99 then next increment should be XX1-XXXXX.01.01.02.00 and it continues for next node also.

XX1-XXXXX.01.01.01.01 is in Character Format.

Any Possible Solution?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking of using the approach of first converting Character Format into Number Format and then do operations on number. After doing certain incrementing operations, appending the resultant number into character I had separated. Although I don't know how to achieve that. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is not compatible down to ABAP 700 like szakos but I want to bring in another solution:

```
FORM increment
  CHANGING
    fcw_out TYPE string.

  DATA lw_as_n TYPE n LENGTH 8.

  SPLIT fcw_out AT '.' INTO DATA(lw_start) DATA(lw_rest).
  REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '.' IN lw_rest WITH ''.
  lw_as_n = lw_rest + 1.

  fcw_out = |{ lw_start }.{ lw_as_n(2) }.{ lw_as_n+2(2) }.{ lw_as_n+4(2) }.{ lw_as_n+6(2) }|.

ENDFORM.

" ------------------------------------------------
" Test run
" ------------------------------------------------

DATA(w_str) = `XX1-XXXXX.01.01.01.99`.

PERFORM increment CHANGING w_str. " ==> XX1-XXXXX.01.01.02.00
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it'll work, I'll give it a shot today. Thanks Again :)

Comment: Yeah, I know... I feel bad too

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by converting the numerical parts of the node to a number and write it back after increasing. Simple example code:

```
DATA: l_node      TYPE c LENGTH 21,
      l_node_new  TYPE c LENGTH 21,
      l_help      TYPE c LENGTH 11,
      l_num       TYPE n LENGTH 8,
      l_node_pos  TYPE int4,
      l_num_pos   TYPE int4.

l_node_new = l_node = 'XX1-XXXXX.01.01.01.01'.
l_help = l_node+10(*).
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '.' IN l_help WITH ''.
CONDENSE l_help.
l_num = l_help.

DO 100 TIMES.
  ADD 1 TO l_num.
ENDDO.

DO 4 TIMES.
  l_node_pos = 10 + ( sy-index - 1 ) * 3.
  l_num_pos  = 0 + ( sy-index - 1 ) * 2.
  l_node_new+l_node_pos(2) = l_num+l_num_pos(2).
ENDDO.

WRITE / l_node.
WRITE / l_node_new.
```

The output is:

[image]

The ABAP version was 700 so this is the "old" syntax, but should work on newer versions.

Comment: Is there a difference between `l_node+10(*)` and `l_node+10`?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'm used to this syntax. :)

Comment: Once a program dumped because the referenced variable got shorter (I think the data element changed) and the program did'nt follow the change, so the fixed length version broke. That's why I started using this syntax. Means the rest of the string for me. Clearer.

Comment: Thanks @szako. For now, I am referring lausek code. Maybe for other scenario it will be useful.